# How do we convert or copy values of a column in apache spark dataframe into a list?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe

I have an apache spark data frame with two columns and I want to copy all values in the second column into a list. Let me know if any one way to do this. I am new to spark

Comment: Can you give a sample dataframe and expected result? It would make the question much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to store the content of the second column of your data frame locally in a list. For this, the following steps can be used. They may not be the fastest or best way:

```
rows = df.select("column_name_2").collect()
# => Returns a list of Rows with one column

my_list = map(lambda x: x["column_name_2"], rows)
# => Extracts the column value out of the row construct
```

You don't have to select the column in the first line, however it reduces the space required to store the rows in driver memory.